# 4 pin connector is melting even with 5 volt and 0.1 amp power supply, Why?

Tags: connector, shielding, video-transmitter, wire-size

I am using a connector as shown:

[image: 4 pin mini round connector].

I am using this to connect to my camera, which works at 5 volts and 0.1 Amp. But this connector works only for few days and then the plastic portion of the connector melts as shown in figure.

[image: strong text]

This connector as per the data sheet can work with 240 volt and 2 amp. Here are the 4 four wire configurations for 4 pins in connector

1. 5V power supply
2. GND
3. Video input signal
4. Earthing of the shield covering all the wires.

One thing which I know for sure is the Impedance mismatch. I am supposed to use a 75 ohm wire but because of many other reasons I am using 100 ohm wire.

- Can this cause the issue?
- What are the ways to find out the reason of breaking ?

(I can clearly make out that the plastic portion is melting because of heat, I tried different connectors as well but the result is same )

This has ruined my sleep for many weeks. Kindly suggest me a solution.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

IF the voltage is indeed 5 v and current at 0.1A, this should not happen, as you are expecting.

Make some arrangement to measure voltage as well as the current when the device is being used. One of the measurement will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Soma, Rajesh is correct. You are pulling a LOT more than 100ma. Even if the connector has a bad contact, 100ma isn't enough to heat it that much. Maybe there's an intermittent short in or after the connector, or maybe it draws a lot of current when the flash is charging?

Comment: @Digiproc, if it happens with all connectors he is trying, the female connector shown in the first image may have short which heats up and as metal contacts are there, result shows up in the male connector as melted plastic. He should diagnose the problem ASAP otherwise his costly camera may become just a show piece.

Comment: @ rajesh and @ Digiproc : Thank you for your valuable comments. I have checked the voltage but not the current. I will check it come back soon.